# Proving a subset of a metric space is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Having a bit of trouble with this question. Would appreciate a basic outline of what needs to be done to prove it, as although I have an idea of the required definitions I've no clue how to apply them.

*Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Prove that $A ⊂ X$ is **bounded** if and only if
$A ⊂ Br(a)$ for some $a ∈ X$ and $r > 0$.*

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT

From my notes ;

$A$ is a subset of a metric space and diameter of a A is defined as *$diam(A)=sup$ {$d$ $(x,y)| x,y∈A$}*. $A$ is bounded if $diam(A)<∞$.

AND

A subset $A$ of a metric space is only bounded if there exists an open ball $Br(a)$ such that $A⊂Br(a)$.

Comment: You should mention what is the definition of *bounded*, since what you are asked to prove could be a definition.

Comment: I've added two definitions that should clear that up. I'm aware of the link between the second one and what is asked in the question but I'm finding it tough to actually apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A \subseteq B_r(a)$, for some $r \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}, a \in X$. Then $\text{diam}(A) = \sup \{ d(x, y) \mid x, y \in A \}$. But $$d(x, y) \leq d(x, a) + d(a, y) \leq r+r = 2r$$
so $A$ is bounded.

Conversely, suppose $A$ is bounded. Then $D := \sup \{ d(x, y) \mid x, y \in A \}$ is finite. If $A = \emptyset$, we're done instantly as it's contained in every ball; so wlog we're free to pick some $a \in A$, and let $r = D$.

Then every point in $A$ is at most $D$ away from $a$.